# R: df from days to weeks

Tags: r

I have a df with values (website views) per day. However, I want to convert these to views per week, so aggregating the values per week, while keeping the the date-format for my date-column.

The new date-column can be week numbers. Or alternatively, the values for the week (Mon-Sun) can be aggregated on every date that is a Sunday. I've tried the following, but here I lose the date-format:

```
Views %>% group_by(week = week(date)) %>% summarise(value = sum(value))
```

I've tried several other topics here, but haven't been able to reproduce any of the proposed solutions. Is this really so difficult? Or is it me? ;)

This is a section of the df I'm working with:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17591, 17592, 17593, 17594, 
17595, 17596, 17597, 17598, 17599, 17600, 17601, 17602, 17603, 
17604, 17605, 17606, 17607, 17608, 17609, 17610, 17611, 17612, 
17613, 17614, 17615, 17616, 17617, 17618, 17619, 17620, 17621, 
17622, 17623, 17624, 17625, 17626, 17627, 17628, 17629, 17630, 
17631, 17632, 17633, 17634, 17635, 17636, 17637, 17638, 17639, 
17640, 17641, 17642, 17643, 17644, 17645, 17646, 17647, 17648, 
17649, 17650), class = "Date"), UPV = c(69L, 96L, 35L, 37L, 211L, 
128L, 106L, 140L, 84L, 29L, 58L, 125L, 117L, 129L, 160L, 91L, 
41L, 33L, 131L, 172L, 130L, 118L, 91L, 19L, 43L, 136L, 165L, 
142L, 84L, 86L, 22L, 26L, 49L, 191L, 164L, 147L, 104L, 24L, 34L, 
92L, 122L, 125L, 109L, 139L, 23L, 39L, 175L, 140L, 104L, 94L, 
62L, 31L, 35L, 155L, 122L, 99L, 68L, 11L, 26L, 44L)), row.names = c(NA, 
60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Hope this is clear! Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you only need a date to be retained, but the grouping should stay as it is, how about you just add `date_sunday = max(date)` in your `summarise` call?

Comment: This actually came close, but I seem to lose part of my data. The set originally ranges from March 2018 to August 2020. But the new date_sunday column starts on 2019-09-09.

`Views %>% group_by(week = week(date)) %>% summarise(value = sum(value), date_sunday = max(date)) %>%
  arrange(date_sunday)`

Comment: Ah, I see. Since you group only by week but not year, obviously that'll group unrelated weeks together. How about you do `group_by(year (date),week(date))` or `group_by(sunday_date = lubridate::ceiling_date(date, unit = "weeks"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `mutate()` from `dplyr`, it will keep your dates:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
#Code
Views %>% group_by(week = week(date)) %>% mutate(value = sum(UPV))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 60 x 4
# Groups:   week [9]
   date         UPV  week value
   <date>     <int> <dbl> <int>
 1 2018-03-01    69     9   237
 2 2018-03-02    96     9   237
 3 2018-03-03    35     9   237
 4 2018-03-04    37     9   237
 5 2018-03-05   211    10   756
 6 2018-03-06   128    10   756
 7 2018-03-07   106    10   756
 8 2018-03-08   140    10   756
 9 2018-03-09    84    10   756
10 2018-03-10    29    10   756
# ... with 50 more rows
```

**Update:** Using next code as suggested by @alex_jwb90:

```
Views %>% group_by(week = week(date)) %>%
  summarise(date=max(date),value = sum(UPV)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value))+geom_col()
```

You get this output:

[image]

**Update 2:**

After exploring data properly the next code can be useful:

```
#Data
df2 <- df %>% mutate(Var=format(date,'%Y-%m')) %>%
  group_by(Var) %>%
  summarise(Value=sum(value))
#Plot
ggplot(df2,aes(x=factor(Var),y=Value))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: I see what you're doing, but it doesn't seem right when I try to plot it: 

`Views %>% group_by(week = week(date)) %>% mutate(value = sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value))+geom_col()`

Comment: @Justin I read your update in the question. Just a moment!

Comment: @Justin I have updated with a plot, please check and let me know if that works!

Comment: Yeah, so this works for the subset, but not for the entire dataset. It cuts part of the dataset off for some reason, starting at 2019-09-09, while the dataset consist of values starting 2018-03-01.

Comment: @Justin It is pretty weird could you please tell the structure of your data with `str(yourdata)`

Comment: `data.frame': 915 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date : Date, format: "2018-03-01" "2018-03-02" "2018-03-03" ...
 $ value: int  69 96 35 37 211 128 106 140 84 29 ...`

Comment: @Justin Pretty weird, I would like to help you if you want. You can open a chat and invite me https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220916/discussion-between-justin-and-duck).

Comment: @Justin I have edited the question according what we checked early.